# How can I use GLMatrix to do matrix multiplications?

Tags: javascript, gl-matrix

I'm just beginning to try to find/use a matrix operations library for JS.  I want to do simple translation, scale, and rotation operations on 2D matrices.  The [mozilla developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Matrix_math_for_the_web) recommends [GLMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) for its "focus on speed and performance."

I'm just wanting to do some simple 2D transformations on matrices, e.g. using `mat2d`.  I want to do something like this:

```js
var a = mat2d.fromValues(2,0,2,0,0,0);
var b = mat2d.fromValues(1,3,3,1,-1,-2);
var ans = mat2d();

mat2d.multiply(ans,a,b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

but I must not have the syntax right because I get an `Uncaught TypeError: mat2d is not a function` ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqh3840n/)).  I am using `GL-matrix-min.js` found [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js).

**How can I fix my matrix multiplication code snippet above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var ans = mat2d.create();
```

to create a new (identity) matrix. See the [docs](http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat2d.html#.create) or the [source](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/mat2d.js#L48).

Comment: Thank you; that works.  Question, though: right above that function (in the [source](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/mat2d.js#L41) ) is a line that says `var mat2d = {};`.  Wouldn't that create a blank mat2d object?

Comment: @user203212546 no it just creates the "namespace". (an empty object, basically used as a dictionary for functions)

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you for your help.